# Unable to center Text in a button

Tags: android, android-layout

This is quiet straight forward. But don't know why this isn't working.

This is the Code i have in the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue9Patch"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:text="One" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareProductButton_shareOptions"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue9Patch"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:text="Two" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what i get in the **Graphical** Layout in Eclipse:

[image]

But on the **emulator** it is like this:

[image]

This is the 9-patch image i am using as a Background

[image]

Thought, on device it would work fine, but didn't.

I want it to be like the first image.

Thank You.

Comment: any `9patch` (with setting content area) image used?

Comment: Yeah the background is a 9 patch image. Wait i will upload that  too

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you need to define the weigh sum of your linear layout.....     android:weightSum="2.0"..... Thus the 1.0 weights of each button will each take 50% of the container width.

Comment: side tip: Usually the 9 image are smaller than the image you provided. I mean it should be a bit more smaller in width. Have a look at [this post for clear idea of 9 patch](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-how-to-use-9-patch-png.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly I assume you had used .9Patch image with setting content area i.e. assigning pixels on Right and Bottom part. you just need to clear that assignment or just fill all the Bottom and Right end pixel(padding box). Thats it.

[image]

Finally this one

[image]

Comment: Yeah. But i didn't give anything on the right and bottom of the 9-patch. Since it is optional i thought it will take whole width and height by deafault. So, should i add it?

Comment: see latest image, sometimes it creates problem, Better to assign whole area. O wow a downvote!

Comment: Adding one more thing, assigning pixel give it from `center`. sometimes that is also a culprit.

Comment: Fine. will do that too. But may i know why?